# How to wrap with boost-python a virtual class with a method returning a reference

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I have two virtual classes I would like to wrap in boost python, I want to be able to write Python class that extends them. The thing is, one of the classes has a method that return a reference of the other class, and I can't figure how to do.

Here is a simplified version of code of class to be wrapped.

```
class Foo
{
    public:
    virtual ~Foo() {}
    virtual int a() = 0;
};

class Bar
{
    public:
    virtual ~Bar() {}
    virtual Foo const& b() = 0;
};
```

So I started wrapping about this way.

```
class FooWrap : public Foo, public wrapper<Foo>
{
    public:
    int a()
    {
        return this->get_override("a")();
    }
};

class BarWrap : public Bar, public wrapper<Bar>
{
    public:
    Foo const& b()
    {
        return this->get_override("b")();
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foobar)
{
    class_<FooWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Foo")
        .def("a", pure_virtual(&Foo::a))
        ;
    class_<BarWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Bar")
        .def("b", pure_virtual(&Bar::b))
        ;
}
```

And I get a compile error about "cannot instantiate abstract class [...]
pure virtual function was not defined" "see declaration of 'foo::a'"

Comment: what if the virtual functions and the inheritance of the wrapper classes are public ?

Comment: No, setting everything public doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @MatthieuW Is modifying the return type of the functions to a smart pointer an option?

Comment: @Paul-Manta No, my goal is to test a c++ library, I can't change its interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been able to compile and run your code after I added call policy for `Bar::b` function:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foobar)
{
    class_<FooWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Foo")
        .def("a", pure_virtual(&Foo::a));

    class_<BarWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Bar")
        .def("b", pure_virtual(&Bar::b),
             return_internal_reference<>());
}
```

Basically, it's just means that lifetime of returned reference from `Bar::b` should be dependent on lifetime of `Bar` instance. You can read about call policies in [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/functions.html#python.call_policies).

What compiler and boost version are you using? I've got the following descriptive error with boost 1.46.0 and gcc 4.6.1:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(const boost::python::detail::specify_a_return_value_policy_to_wrap_functions_returning<const Foo&>) (const Foo&)’
```

Comment: I use boost 1.47.0 and VC 7.1

Comment: There are comments in boost docs for MSVC 6 and 7: you should try `return call<int>(this->get_override("a").ptr());`.

Comment: That's it. The MSVC 7 thing. Until now I used the usual syntax and it was working fine, so I thought the MSVC 7 special syntax were no more needed. Actually it is in some cases.

Comment: To be more precise, it is needed for method b. return boost::python::call<Foo const&>(this->get_override("b").ptr());

Answer (score 3):

The following code compiles for me. Inside your python Bar subclass you should be able to return a Foo instance from the b method.

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class Foo
{
public:
    virtual ~Foo() {}
    virtual int a() = 0;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    virtual ~Bar() {}
    virtual Foo const& b() = 0;
};


class FooWrap : public Foo, public boost::python::wrapper<Foo>
{
    public:
    int a()
    {
        return this->get_override("a")();
    }
};

class BarWrap : public Bar, public boost::python::wrapper<Bar>
{
    public:
    Foo const& b()
    {
        return this->get_override("b")();
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foobar)
{
    boost::python::class_<FooWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Foo")
        .def("a", boost::python::pure_virtual(&Foo::a)) ;

    boost::python::class_<BarWrap, boost::noncopyable>("Bar")
        .def("b", boost::python::pure_virtual(&Bar::b), boost::python::return_internal_reference<>());
}
```